# Rails and before_action with different conditionals

Tags: ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-6

I have these `before_action`s set in my Controller:

```
before_action :require_user, unless: :public?, only: [:show]
before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
```

Basically I am trying execute the filter `required_front_user` in the `show` action only if the `public?` is false.

for the rest of actions I want the filter to be executed always.

Looks like the first `before_action` set up is ignored and totally override by the second set up.

Is it possible to combine both combinations using `before_action` statements or do I have to implement this logic in the filter it self?

#### Update

This also doesn't work:

```
before_action :require_user, if: :public?, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_action :require_user, unless: :public?, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update]
```

I thought if `public?` returns `true` the first set up will be loaded, and if `false` the second set up will be loaded. It happens that only the second set up is loaded and if `public? == true` the `before_action` is never triggered

#### Update 2

This is what I found it works:

```
before_action :require_user_when_public, if: :public?, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_action :require_user_when_no_public, unless: :public?, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update]

protected

def require_user_when_public
  require_user
end

def require_user_when_no_public
  require_user
end
```

Which is very ugly :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most clean way I have found is:

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_action :require_user_when_no_public, unless: :public?, only: [:show]

protected 

def require_user_when_no_public
  require_user
end
```

Comment: (Part 1) I think that this answer is potentially problematic. You could have a callback that you want to run only once per request; for instance, a check login method could lock out a user account after a number of failed login attempts; if the login method runs twice for some reason, the attempts the user has could effectively be halved.

Comment: (Part 2) If the above is a real concern then any time you add the callback to the queue more than once you need to make sure that each of the conditions for the callbacks are mutually exclusive otherwise you could have some difficult to detect and difficult to debug issues.

Comment: (Part 3) This seems like a big maintenance burden to me and makes me wonder if the inability to add the same callback twice in Rails is intended behaviour.

Comment: @BenStephens you may be right in all your concerns, still, in my opinion, this is the more readable, maintainable and debuggable solution so I accept this one as the answer until I don't see there is some up votes in the other answers or a new one appears

Answer (score 0):

```rb
before_action :require_user, only: require_user_before_actions

private

def require_user_before_actions
 actions = [:index, :edit, :update]
 actions << :show unless public?
 actions
end
```

Comment: Good idea, I tried but I get this error `undefined local variable or method `require_user_before_actions'`. It has sense du the before_action is called in class loading time and the method has to be defined as instance class. I tried variants: `only: -> { require_user_before_actions }` or `only: :require_user_before_actions` but the method `require_user_before_actions` is never called and the `before_action` never executed

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested this a tiny bit so not super sure it'll work, but maybe something like:

```
before_action :require_user, if: ->(c) {
  [:index, :edit, :update, !public? && :show].include?(c.action_name.to_sym)
}
```

As a possibly dumb / broken (that seems to work in a basic test for me as far as I can tell) alternative, possibly something like:

```
class <<self
  alias_method :old_before_action, :before_action
end

def self.before_action(*callbacks)
  options = callbacks.extract_options!
  if options[:only] && options[:only].is_a?(Proc)
    only_proc = options.delete(:only)
    if_proc = ->(c) { Array(only_proc.(c)).reject(&:blank?).map(&:to_s).to_set.include? c.action_name }
    options[:if] = Array(options[:if]).unshift(if_proc)
  end
  old_before_action(*callbacks, options)
end

before_action :require_user, only: ->(c) { [:index, :edit, :update, !public? && :show] }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the condition to the method body (and name)?

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_action :require_user_unless_public, only: [:show]

private

def require_user_unless_public
  require_user unless public?
end
```

Also, it would probably be better to use `except`:

```
before_action :require_user, except: [:show]
before_action :require_user_unless_public, only: [:show]
```